# Can react-redux connect() -ed containers implement lifecyle methods like componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've come across a repeated pattern in my react-redux site:
A component displays data from a web api, and it should be populated on load, automatically, without any user interaction.

**I want to initiate the async fetch from a container component, but as far as I can tell the only way to do it is from a lifecycle event in a display component.** This seems to make it impossible to put all the logic in the container and only use dumb stateless functional components for display.

This means I can't use a stateless functional component for any component that needs async data. That doesn't seem right.

It seems like the "right" way to do this would be to somehow initiate async calls from the **container**. Then when the call returned, the state would be updated and the container would get the new state and would in turn pass those to its stateless component via `mapStateToProps()`.

Making async calls in `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` (I mean actually calling the async function, as opposed to returning it as a property) doesn't make sense.

So what I've ended up doing is putting the async call(s) in a `refreshData()` function exposed by `mapDispatchToProps()`, then calling it from two or more of the React lifecycle methods: `componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps`.

**Is there a clean way to update the redux store state without putting lifecycle method calls in every component that needs async data?**

Should I be making these calls higher up the component heierarchy (thereby reducing the scope of this issue, since only "top-level" components would need to listen to lifecycle events)?

### **Edit**:

Just so there's no confusion what I mean by a connect()ed container component, here's a very simple example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {action} from './actions.js';

import MyDumbComponent from './myDumbComponent.jsx';

function mapStateToProps(state)
{
  return { something: state.xxxreducer.something  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
  return { 
       doAction: ()=>{dispatch(action())}
  };
}

const MyDumbComponentContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyDumbComponent);

// Uh... how can I hook into to componentDidMount()? This isn't 
// a normal React class.

export default MyDumbComponentContainer;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jamie Dixon](https://github.com/JamieDixon) has written a package to do this!

https://github.com/JamieDixon/react-lifecycle-component

Usage would look like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    componentDidMount: getAllTehDatas
}

...

export default connectWithLifecycle(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WrappedComponent)
```

Answer (score 7):

**edit**
With hooks you are now able to implement lifecycle callbacks in a stateless functional component. While this may not directly address all of the points in the question, it may also get around some of the reason for wanting to do what was originally proposed.

---

**edit to original answer**
After the discussion in comments and thinking about it more, this answer is more exploratory and can serve as a piece of the conversation.  But I don't think it's the right answer.

**original answer**

On the Redux site there's [an example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html#containersasyncappjs) that shows you don't have to do both mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.  You can just leverage `connect`'s awesomeness for the props, and use a class and implement the lifecycle methods on the dumb component.

In the example, the connect call is even in the same file and the dumb component isn't even exported, so to the user of the component it's looks the same.

I can understand not wanting to issue async calls from the display component.  I think there's a distinction between issuing the async calls from there and dispatching an action which, with thunks, moves the issuing of the async calls up into the actions (even more decoupled from the React code).

As an example, here's a splash screen component where I'd like to do some async action (like asset preloading) when the display component mounts:

SplashContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Splash from '../components/Splash'
import * as actions from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // whatever you need here
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onMount: () => dispatch(actions.splashMount())
  }
}

const SceneSplash = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Splash)

export default SceneSplash
```

Splash.js

```
import React from 'react'

class Splash extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="scene splash">
      <span className="fa fa-gear fa-spin"></span>
      </div>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { onMount } = this.props
    onMount()
  }
}

export default Splash
```

You can see the the dispatch happens in the connected container, and you can imagine in the `actions.splashMount()` call we issue an async http request or do other async things via [thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or promises.

**edit to clarify**

Allow me to try to defend the approach.  I re-read the question and am not 100% sure I'm addressing the main thing it's after, but bear with me.  If I am still not quite on track, I have a modified approach below that may be closer to the mark.

"it should be populated on load" - the example above accomplishes this

"I want to initiate the async fetch from a container" - in the example it's not initiated from the display component or the container, but from an async action

"This seems to make it impossible to put all the logic in the container" - I think you can still put any additional logic needed in the container.  As noted, the data loading code isn't in the display component (or the container) but in the async action creator.

"This means I can't use a stateless functional component for any component that needs async data." - in the above example the display component is stateless and functional.  The only link is the lifecycle method invoking a callback.  It need not know or care what that callback does.  It is not a case of the display component trying to be the owner of async data fetching - it's merely letting the code that does handle that know when a particular thing has happened.

So far I'm attempting to justify how the example given meets the question's requirements.  That said, if what you're after is having a display component that contains absolutely no code related to the async data load even by indirect callbacks - that is, the only link it has is to consume that data via the props it's handed when that remote data comes down, then I would suggest something like this:

SplashContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Splash from '../components/Splash'
import * as actions from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // whatever you need here
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actions.splashMount())
  return {
    // whatever else here may be needed
  }
}

const SceneSplash = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Splash)

export default SceneSplash
```

Splash.js

```
import React from 'react'

class Splash extends React.Component {
  // incorporate any this.props references here as desired
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="scene splash">
      <span className="fa fa-gear fa-spin"></span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Splash
```

By dispatching the action in mapDispatchToProps you are letting the code for that action reside entirely in the container.  In fact, you are starting the async call as soon as the container is instantiated, rather than waiting for the connected display component to spin up and be mounted.  However, if you cannot begin the async call until the componentDidMount() for the display component fires, I think you're inherently bound to have code like in my first example.

I haven't actually tested this second approach to see if react or redux will complain about it, but it should work.  You have access to the dispatch method and should be able to call it without problems.

To be honest, this second example, while removing all code related to the async action from the display component does kind of strike me as a bit funny since we're doing non-mapping-of-dispatch-to-props things in the eponymous function.  And containers don't actually have a componentDidMount to run it in otherwise.  So I'm a bit squirmy with it and would lean toward the first approach.  It's not clean in the "feels right" sense, but it is in the "simple 1-liner" sense.

Comment: ? This answer does exactly what my question is about avoiding. Not sure you understood the question.

Comment: @skypecakes :) I'm not sure either.  I went ahead and added an edit to the answer.  Let me know if I'm in the ballpark or still missing the gist of it.

Comment: You nailed it right on the head with this: "... containers don't actually have a componentDidMount to run it in otherwise." That's what this whole question is about. Why couldn't they? They're just generated React components. If the dumb component has to announce "Hey I've been mounted," that seems to contradict the one-way-data-flow model that react-redux seems to be all about.

Comment: "in the above example the display component is stateless and functional." That is true in a literal sense :-), but I'm using React jargon, not really English. A "stateless functional component" is, by definition, defined as a function, not as a class. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components.

Comment: Mmm - right. It does seem like whatever workaround is used is just that - a workaround. If the point of connect() is simply to do what it's name suggests it seems like it would be most useful if it exposed the full API of the component it wraps. Would be interesting to see what the conversation around the design was regarding not having the usual lifecycle methods on generated components

Comment: While I think it would be nice to have an ability to do something like `connectedComponent.componentDidMount = () => { /*whatever*/}` your example seems 100% legit. It maintains separation between components and containers as well as as properly calls dispatch and passes props to nested component

Comment: FWIW, since posting I've started using Inferno a bit (nearly identical API to React, more performant, written by a developer now on the FB React team, 10k github stars, no patent-grant licence entanglements, etc. if you're not familiar with it... `</shamelessPlug>`).  It has the added benefit of supporting lifecycle methods on connected containers themselves!  Just the ticket (if you're able to switch).

Comment: Revisiting this: I wonder now if maybe having either the container or the display component be the thing that triggers the async operation is right.  Perhaps both the view (containers + display components) _and_ the async data fetch should be triggered by the store reaching a given state.  So, rather than going from state > react > data fetch, maybe the right thing is to go from state > other things (including react and data fetch).

Answer (score 2):

Check out redux-saga https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga.  It's a redux middleware component that creates long-lived watchers that look for specific store actions and can trigger functions or generator functions in response.  The generator syntax is particular nice for handling async, and redux-saga has some nice helpers that allow you to treat async code in a synchronous fashion.  See some of their examples.  https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/async/src/sagas/index.js . The generator syntax can be hard to grok at first, but based on our experience this syntax supports extremely complex async logic, including debounce, cancellation and joining/racing multiple requests.

Comment: Sounds fantastic. I keep seeing mentions of redux-saga, will check it out!

Comment: I'm using saga, but still don't see how this answers the question?

Comment: If you are using redux-saga or really any other good async solution for redux, you don't need to use life-cycle methods to do fetching.  We have sagas that are imported into UI components that will fetch a particular bit of data, perhaps a list of valid values, and put it into the store.  Then the UI component connects to that bit of the store.

Comment: @joshv I still don't understand. I have the same question as @Waclock—how does this avoid using lifecycle hooks in a stateless functional component? (What do you mean by "sagas that are imported into UI components"? Doesn't that mean the component still has to call it from `componentDidMount`?)

redux-saga looks awesome, by the way—thanks for the tip!

Comment: The original questioner said "I want to initiate the async fetch from a container component, but as far as I can tell the only way to do it is from a lifecycle event in a display component. This seems to make it impossible to put all the logic in the container and only use dumb stateless functional components for display."

redux-saga moves async out of component code.  Fetches are triggered by user actions or can be triggered on application load - and they put their data into the store.  Using react-redux, stateless components can then render this data.  We do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from a container.  Just make a component that extends React.Component but name it with "Container" somewhere in the name.  Then use that **container's *componentDidMount*** instead of using **componentDidMount** in the **presentational (dumb) component** that the container component renders.  Reducer will see that you've dispatched an action still, and still update state so your dumb component will be able to get at that data..

I TDD but even if I didn't TDD I separate out my dumb vs container components via file.  I hate having too much in one file, especially if mixing dumb vs. container stuff in the same file, that's a mess.  I know people do it, but I think that's awful.

I do this:

`src/components/someDomainFolder/someComponent.js` (dumb component)
`src/components/someDomainFolder/someComponentContainer.js` (for example you might use React-Redux..have connected **container** not a connected presentational component..and so in someComponentContainer.js you DO have a react class in this file, as stated, just call it someComponentContainer extends React.Component for example.

Your mapStateToProps() and mapDispatchToProps() would be global functions of that connected container component outside that container class.  And connect() would render the container, which would render the presentational component but this allows you to keep all your behavior in your container file, away from dumb presentational component code.

that way you have tests around someComponent that are structural/state based and you have behavior tests around the Container component. Much better route to be going with maintaining and writing tests, and maintaining and making things easy for yourself or other devs to see what's going on and to manage dumb vs. behavioral components.

Doing things this way, your presentational stuff is separated both physically by file AND by code convention.  AND your tests are grouped around the right areas of code...not an intermingled mess.  AND if you do this, and use a reducer that listens to update state, your presentational component can remain totally stupid....and just look for that updates state via props...since you're using mapStateToProps().

Comment: So wrap the dumb component inside a React component class that exists solely to fire the lifecycle methods. Not a bad idea. That's pretty much what react-lifecycle-component does, except that you don't have to write all the boilerplate code for the wrapper class because the library wraps it for you. You can instead just define your lifecycle methods in mapDispatchToProps(). But I could see value in separating your lifecycle methods into a separate file like you do.

Comment: Some feedback for your answer: A full code example would be easier to read than description text, in my opinion.

Comment: I'll get back to you, super busy this month

Comment: And personally I think things like saga are HUGE bloat and over complicates everything

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @PositiveGuy suggestion, here is example code of how to implement a container component that can utilize lifecycle methods. I think this is a pretty clean approach that maintains separation of concerns keeping the presentation component "dumb":

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { myAction } from './actions/my_action_creator'
import MyPresentationComponent from './my_presentation_component'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    myStateSlice: state.myStateSlice
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    myAction: () => {
      dispatch(myAction())
    }
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //You have lifecycle access now!!
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <MyPresentationComponent
        myStateSlice={this.props.myStateSlice}
        myAction={this.props.myAction}
      />
    )
  }
}

const ContainerComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Container)

export default ContainerComponent
```

Answer (score -2):

You CAN initiate an async fetch from the parent container (the smart container). You write the function in the smart container and you pass the function as a prop for the dumb container. For example:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  onClick: function(){
    dispatch(myAsyncAction());
  },
  render: function() {
    return <childComp onClick={this.onClick} />;
  }
});

var childComp = React.createClass({
    propTypes:{
    onClick: React.PropTypes.func
  },
  render: function() {
    return <Button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click me</Button>;
  }
});
```

childComp is stateless since the onClick definition is determined by the parent.

EDIT: Added connected container example below, excluded other stuff for brevity. Doesn't really show much, and it's a bit cumbersome to setup on fiddle and stuff, point is, I do use lifecycle methods in connected containers and it works out fine for me.

```
class cntWorkloadChart extends Component {

    ...

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.myStuff.isData){
            if (nextProps.myStuff.isResized) {
                this.onResizeEnd();
            }

            let temp = this.updatePrintingData(nextProps)
            this.selectedFilterData = temp.selectedFilterData;
            this.selectedProjects = temp.selectedProjects;

            let data = nextProps.workloadData.toArray();

            let spread = [];
            if(nextProps.myStuff.isSpread) { 
                spread = this.updateSelectedProjectSpread(nextProps);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].sumBillableHrsSelectedProjects = spread[data[i].weekCode] ? Number(spread[data[i].weekCode].sumBillableHrsSelectedProjects.toFixed(1)) : 0;
                    data[i].sumCurrentBudgetHrsSelectedProjects = spread[data[i].weekCode] ? Number(spread[data[i].weekCode].sumCurrentBudgetHrsSelectedProjects.toFixed(1)) : 0;
                    data[i].sumHistoricBudgetHrsSelectedProjects = spread[data[i].weekCode] ? Number(spread[data[i].weekCode].sumHistoricBudgetHrsSelectedProjects.toFixed(1)) : 0;
                }
            }

            if (nextProps.potentialProjectSpread.length || this.props.potentialProjectSpread.length) { //nextProps.myStuff.isPpSpread) { ???? - that was undefined
                let potential = nextProps.potentialProjectSpread;
                let ppdd = _.indexBy(potential, 'weekCode');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].sumSelectedPotentialProjects = ppdd[data[i].weekCode] ? ppdd[data[i].weekCode].sumSelectedPotentialProjects.toFixed(1) : 0;
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let currObj = data[i];
                currObj.sumCurrentBudgetHrs = currObj.currentBudgeted.sumWeekHours;
                currObj.sumHistoricBudgetHrs = currObj.historicBudgeted.sumWeekHours;
                currObj.fillAlpha = .6; //Default to .6 before any selections are made

                //RMW-TODO: Perhaps we should update ALL line colors this way? This would clean up zero total bars in all places
                this.updateLineColor(currObj, "sumSelectedPotentialProjects", "potentialLineColor", potentialLineColor);
                this.updateLineColor(currObj, "sumHistoricBudgetHrs", "histLineColor", histBudgetLineColor);
                this.updateLineColor(currObj, "sumHistoricBudgetHrsSelectedProjects", "histSelectedLineColor", selectedHistBudgetFillColor);


            }
            if(nextProps.myStuff.isSelectedWeek){
                let currWeekIndex = nextProps.weekIndex.index; 
                let selectedWeek = data[currWeekIndex].fillAlpha = 1.0;
            }

            if(data.length > 0){
                if(data[0].targetLinePercentages && data.length > 9) { //there are target lines and more than 10 items in the dataset
                    let tlHigh = data[0].targetLinePercentages.targetLineHigh;
                    let tlLow = data[0].targetLinePercentages.targetLineLow;
                    if (tlHigh > 0 && tlLow > 0) {
                        this.addTargetLineGraph = true; 
                        this.upperTarget = tlHigh;
                        this.lowerTarget = tlLow;
                    } 
                }
                else {
                    this.addTargetLineGraph = false;
                    this.upperTarget = null;
                    this.lowerTarget = null;
                }
            }
            this.data = this.transformStoreData(data); 
            this.containsHistorical = nextProps.workloadData.some(currObj=> currObj.historicBudgeted.projectDetails.length);
        }

    }

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="chartContainer" className="container">
                <WorkloadChart workloadData={this.props.workloadData} 
                                onClick={this.onClick} 
                                onResizeEnd={this.onResizeEnd}
                                weekIndex={this.props.weekIndex} 
                                getChartReference={this.getChartReference}
                                //projectSpread={this.props.projectSpread}
                                selectedRows={this.props.selectedRows}
                                potentialProjectSpread={this.props.potentialProjectSpread}
                                selectedCompany={this.props.selectedCompany} 
                                cascadeFilters={this.props.cascadeFilters} 
                                selectedRows={this.props.selectedRows} 
                                resized={this.props.resized} 
                                selectedFilterData={this.selectedFilterData}
                                selectedProjects={this.selectedProjects}
                                data={this.data}
                                upperTarget={this.upperTarget}
                                lowerTarget={this.lowerTarget}
                                containsHistorical={this.containsHistorical}
                                addTargetLineGraph={this.addTargetLineGraph}
        />


            </div> 
        );
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state){
    let myValues = getChartValues(state);
    return {
        myStuff: myValues,
        workloadData: state.chartData || new Immutable.List(),
        weekIndex: state.weekIndex || null,
        //projectSpread: state.projectSpread || {},
        selectedRows: state.selectedRows || [],
        potentialProjectSpread: state.potentialProjectSpread || [],
        selectedCompany: state.companyFilter.selectedItems || null,
        brokenOutByCompany: state.workloadGrid.brokenOutByCompany || false,
        gridSortName: state.projectGridSort.name,
        gridSortOrder: state.projectGridSort.order,
        cascadeFilters: state.cascadeFilters || null,
        selectedRows: state.selectedRows || [],
        resized: state.chartResized || false,
        selectedPotentialProjects: state.selectedPotentialProjects || []
    };

}
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)(cntWorkloadChart);
```

Comment: My question is about displaying async data immediately on loading, not in response to a user action. Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Also, this is about react-redux. Containers are defined very differently with react-redux. And you're still __initiating__ the fetch from the dumb component. Not calling the async function, but starting the chain of events that causes it to be called.

Comment: @skypecakes imo, initiating the fetch and calling the async function is the same thing. You can use redux-thunk to asynchronously fetch the data that you want -> dispatch an action in response to the fetched data  -> change in state -> mapStateToProps in the container gets called. How do you distinguish between initiating and calling the async function?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a good place to call the async function automatically as (or before) the component loads. Generally that means doing it in a lifecycle event e.g. componentDidMount, but that's not available in redux connect()ed containers as far as I know. I can't very well bring up an empty site with a button on it that says "click to load the site." :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can call lifecycle methods in connected containers. Doing that quite extensively in the project i'm working on. But yeah, seems like you need something to hook onto the routing aspects of your project rather than lifecycle methods, since that's what the data depends on right? (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @skypecakes edited my answer for the example. Was that what you were looking forr?

Comment: No, you have defined lifecycle methods in your component, not in the container. In the react-redux world your `cntWorkloadChart` is considered to be the component. The return value of `connect()` is the container.

Comment: To expand on that, connect() "does not modify the passed React component. It returns a new, connected component, that you should use instead... A React component class that injects state and action creators into your component according to the specified options." It's within that generated component that I would like to hook into the lifecycle methods. Not because it's not possible to do it in the dumb component, but because the logic "belongs" in the container. https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: I don't see why you need access to the container. It not much different from the component. The idea of a container has nothing to do with lifecycle methods, doing anything in the "component" will translate over to the container the same, it just serves as a link to the store. _"Technically, a container component is just a React component that uses store.subscribe() to read a part of the Redux state tree and supply props to a presentational component it renders"_ http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html